# mysql replication on same server instances not working

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I use sqlyog tool to work in MySQL. MySQL master-slave replication on same server replicates fine by using queries and restoring from the sqldump. But it doesn't replicate by using sqlyog tool.

In create query or any other table related query , when we mention DB name along with table name, it doesn't replicatie.

#### Example of DDL to replicate

```
CREATE TABLE master_db. table1(id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

The below code is the configuration code I used for master slave replication on same server. Please provide me with helpful insights.

```
server-id   =1
report-host=master-is-slave-host
log-bin=mysql-bin.log
log-bin-index=mysql-bin.index
relay-log=mysql-relay-bin.log
relay-log-index=mysql-relay-bin.index
replicate-same-server-id=1
binlog-do-db=replica_1
replicate-rewrite-db=replica_1->replica_2
replicate-do-db=replica_2
```

Comment: This seems wrong:  `replicate-same-server-id=1`.  Are the port numbers different?  Are the `server_id` values different?